# multi css selector but no when one is hidden

Tags: css, css-selectors

lets have this selector

```
.A ~ .A .B{
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

I understand that this will put `padding-top: 0` when at least two elements use class A together with B

now lets assume that there are indeed two elements but one has also display: none

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B"><div> //do not apply this since second div with A is disabled
<div>
<div class="A" style="display:none"><div>
```

in this way how to modify this selector not be applicable since on UI it looks like there just one div.

Comment: Based on your description, it should be `.A ~ .A.B`. Also, is the element hidden via style attribute?

Comment: @SalmanA ok any way how to not apply this when the first div is hidden

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector

Answer (score 2):

No, selector `.A ~ .A .B` means

```css
.A ~ .A .B {color: red;}
```

```html
<div class="A">First element</div>
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">This element will be targeted</div>
</div>
```

Selector, you are looking for is

```css
.A ~ .A.B {color: red}
```

```html
<div class="A">First element</div>
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">This element will not be targeted</div>
</div>
<div class="A B">This element will be targeted</div>
```

Which means sibling of `.A` element and has classes at least `class="A B"`.

Comment: ok so how to avoid applying it when first div has display: none ?

Comment: @kosnkov `:not([style])` attribute selector?

Comment: @pavel that was not his question. The edit invalidates your answer.